# Reference previous row when iterating through dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a simple way to reference the previous row when iterating through a dataframe?
In the following dataframe I would like column B to change to 1 when `A > 1` and remain at 1 until `A < -1`, when it changes to -1.

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
                    A    B
2000-01-01  -0.182994    0
2000-01-02   1.290203    0
2000-01-03   0.245229    0
2000-01-08  -1.230742    0
2000-01-09   0.534939    0
2000-01-10   1.324027    0
```

This is what I've tried to do, but clearly you can't just subtract 1 from the index:

```
for idx,row in df.iterrows():
    if df["A"][idx]<-1:
        df["B"][idx] = -1
    elif df["A"][idx]>1:
        df["B"][idx] = 1
    else: 
        df["B"][idx] = df["B"][idx-1]
```

*I also tried using `get_loc` but got completely lost, I'm sure I'm missing a very simple solution!*

Comment: You could use a variable and set it to the current row at the end of each loop, comparing the next row to it at the beginning of the loop.

Comment: Thank you, I knew there was a really simple solution I was missing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference values in the previous row with map or apply](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23333786/reference-values-in-the-previous-row-with-map-or-apply)

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are trying to do?

```
In [38]: df = DataFrame(randn(10,2),columns=list('AB'))

In [39]: df['B'] = np.nan

In [40]: df.loc[df.A<-1,'B'] = -1

In [41]: df.loc[df.A>1,'B'] = 1

In [42]: df.ffill()
Out[42]: 
          A  B
0 -1.186808 -1
1 -0.095587 -1
2 -1.921372 -1
3 -0.772836 -1
4  0.016883 -1
5  0.350778 -1
6  0.165055 -1
7  1.101561  1
8 -0.346786  1
9 -0.186263  1
```

Comment: +1, but that will fail if the first element is NaN, won't it?  (I.e. don't you need an extra `.fillna(0)` or something?)

Comment: it could generate a ``nan`` in B (for the first n elements actually, if not are abs>1), in this case I think ``nan`` is ok as its undefined by the OP

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect and much faster than a loop too!

Answer (score 1):

Similar question here: [Reference values in the previous row with map or apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23333786/reference-values-in-the-previous-row-with-map-or-apply/38155070#38155070) .
My impression is that pandas should handle iterations and we shouldn't have to do it on our own... Therefore, I chose to use the DataFrame 'apply' method.

Here is the same answer I posted on other question linked above...

You can use the dataframe 'apply' function and leverage the unused the 'kwargs' parameter to store the previous row.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,2], 'b':[0,10,20]})

new_col = 'c'

def apply_func_decorator(func):
    prev_row = {}
    def wrapper(curr_row, **kwargs):
        val = func(curr_row, prev_row)
        prev_row.update(curr_row)
        prev_row[new_col] = val
        return val
    return wrapper

@apply_func_decorator
def running_total(curr_row, prev_row):
    return curr_row['a'] + curr_row['b'] + prev_row.get('c', 0)

df[new_col] = df.apply(running_total, axis=1)

print(df)
# Output will be:
#    a   b   c
# 0  0   0   0
# 1  1  10  11
# 2  2  20  33
```

This example uses a decorator to store the previous row in a dictionary and then pass it to the function when Pandas calls it on the next row.

Disclaimer 1: The 'prev_row' variable starts off empty for the first row so when using it in the apply function I had to supply a default value to avoid a 'KeyError'.

Disclaimer 2: I am fairly certain this will be slower the apply operation but I did not do any tests to figure out how much.

Comment: please update this answer to include the actual answer from your other post (which seems quite good actually).

Comment: Thank you, Joseph.  I have now duplicated my answer here as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: If the first value is neither `>= 1` or  `< -1`  set to `0` or whatever you like.

```
df["B"] = None
df["B"] = np.where(df['A'] >= 1, 1,df['B'])
df["B"] = np.where(df['A'] < -1, -1,df['B'])
df = df.ffill().fillna(0)
```

This solves the problem stated, But the real solution to reference previous row is use  `.shift()`   or  `.index() -1`

Comment: If this answer helped, please upvote and correct if it is.