# Reference values in the previous row with map or apply

Tags: python, pandas

Given a dataframe `df`, I would like to generate a new variable/column for each row based on the values in the previous row. `df` is sorted so that the order of the rows is meaningful.

Normally, we can use either `map` or `apply`, but it seems that neither of them allows the access to values in the previous row.

For example, given existing rows `a b c`, I want to generate a new column `d`, which is based on some calculation using the value of `c` in the previous row.

How should I do it in pandas?

Comment: What would you exactly want to calculate? Can you give a concrete example? It could maybe be done with the `rolling_*` functions (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#moving-rolling-statistics-moments). If it is just based on the previous row, you can also calculate it and then shift it.

Comment: @joris, a very simple example: in the new column `d` above for each row, I want to simply copy the value for `c` in the preceding row. Of course, I will simply set the first row of `df` to `NaN` for column `d`. Could you also illustrate with an example how you do the 'shifting'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to do a calculation based on the previous row, you can calculate and then shift:

```
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,2], 'b':[0,10,20]})

In [3]: df
Out[3]:
   a   b
0  0   0
1  1  10
2  2  20

# a calculation based on other column
In [4]: df['c'] = df['b'] + 1

# shift the column
In [5]: df['c'] = df['c'].shift()

In [6]: df
Out[6]:
   a   b   c
0  0   0 NaN
1  1  10   1
2  2  20  11
```

If you want to do a calculation based on multiple rows, you could look at the `rolling_apply` function (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#moving-rolling-statistics-moments and http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.rolling_apply.html#pandas.rolling_apply)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dataframe 'apply' function and leverage the unused the 'kwargs' parameter to store the previous row.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,2], 'b':[0,10,20]})

new_col = 'c'

def apply_func_decorator(func):
    prev_row = {}
    def wrapper(curr_row, **kwargs):
        val = func(curr_row, prev_row)
        prev_row.update(curr_row)
        prev_row[new_col] = val
        return val
    return wrapper

@apply_func_decorator
def running_total(curr_row, prev_row):
    return curr_row['a'] + curr_row['b'] + prev_row.get('c', 0)

df[new_col] = df.apply(running_total, axis=1)

print(df)
# Output will be:
#    a   b   c
# 0  0   0   0
# 1  1  10  11
# 2  2  20  33
```

This example uses a decorator to store the previous row in a dictionary and then pass it to the function when Pandas calls it on the next row.

Disclaimer 1: The 'prev_row' variable starts off empty for the first row so when using it in the apply function I had to supply a default value to avoid a 'KeyError'.

Disclaimer 2: I am fairly certain this will be slower the apply operation but I did not do any tests to figure out how much.