# Select rows based on column condition and date time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

From below picture, we see that serial C was failed on 3rd January, and A failed on 5th January within 6 days period. I am interested to take samples for 3 days before the failure of each serial number.

[image]

My codes:

```
from pickle import TRUE
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
from datetime import date, timedelta
df = pd.read_csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/JishanAhmed2019/e464ca4da5c871428ca9ed9264467aa0/raw/da3921c1953fefbc66dddc3ce238dac53142dba8/failure.csv',sep='\t')

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
#df.drop(columns=df.columns[0], axis=1, inplace=True)

df = df.sort_values(by="date")
d = datetime.timedelta(days = 3)

df_fail_date = df[df['failure']==1].groupby(['serial_number'])['date'].min()

df_fail_date = df_fail_date - d
df_fail_date
```

I was not not able to move further to sample my data. I am interested to get the following data, that is 3 days before the failure. Serial C had only 1 day available before failure so I wanna keep that one as well. It would be nice to add duration column to count the days before failure occurred. I appreciate your suggestions. Thanks!

Expected output dataframe:
[image]

Comment: hi, perhaps might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36923494/pandas-dataframe-use-previous-row-value-for-complicated-if-conditions-to-deter

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `groupby.rolling` to get the dates/serials to keep, then `merge` to select:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

N = 3

m = (df.sort_values(by='date')
     .loc[::-1]
     .groupby('serial_number', group_keys=False)
     .rolling(f'{N+1}d', on='date')
     ['failure'].max().eq(1)
     .iloc[::-1]
     )

out = df.merge(m[m], left_on=['serial_number', 'date'],
               right_index=True, how='right')
```

Output:

```
         date serial_number  failure_x  smart_5_raw  smart_187_raw  failure_y
2  2014-01-01             C          0            0             80       True
8  2014-01-02             C          0            0            200       True
4  2014-01-03             C          1            0            120       True
7  2014-01-02             A          0            0            180       True
5  2014-01-03             A          0            0            140       True
9  2014-01-04             A          0            0            280       True
14 2014-01-05             A          1            0            400       True
```

Comment: @ForestGump sorry but I think this answer is matching your expected output. You actually have 2 days of C before it's failure, and maybe there's one more day for A, @mozway?

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew Yes, you are right! I missed on entries of C. By the way, it is still missing one A serial!

Comment: @ForestGump I think you might want 4d (current + 3d before)

Comment: @mozway How failure column is transformed into failure_x and failure_y?

Comment: Oops I missed that. This is due to the `merge`. Add `suffixes=(None, '_drop')` as parameter and drop the unwanted column in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
N = 4

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

(df[df.groupby('serial_number')['failure'].transform(sum) == 1]
 .sort_values(by=['serial_number', 'date'])
 .groupby('serial_number')
 .apply(lambda g:
   g.assign(duration=1+np.arange(min(0, min(N, len(g))-len(g)), min(N, len(g)))))
 .loc[lambda x: x['duration'] > 0]
 .reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output:

```
        date serial_number  failure  smart_5_raw  smart_187_raw  duration
0 2014-01-02             A        0            0            180         1
1 2014-01-03             A        0            0            140         2
2 2014-01-04             A        0            0            280         3
3 2014-01-05             A        1            0            400         4
4 2014-01-01             C        0            0             80         1
5 2014-01-02             C        0            0            200         2
6 2014-01-03             C        1            0            120         3
```